# Trim last few video frames using command line tools only

Tags: debian, video

I am using GStreamer to record to video. 
Sometimes during synchronization, I need to trim off the last few frames ~15frames or so.

What is the fastest tool to do so, that can be launched from the command line?

The file is encoded H.264 avi.
The platform is Debian armel for ARM.

Comment: So you know how many frames without looking at the files?

Comment: @Anthon i use tcprobe to get the number of frames.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest getting familiar with [MELT](http://mltframework.org/twiki/bin/view/MLT/MltMelt).

Edit: Upon further research your answer may be found at [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59383/extract-part-of-a-video-with-a-one-line-command)